# Screenshot for video files

Tags: c#, .net, directx, screenshot, windows-api-code-pack

I am trying to create screenshots of a powerpoint presentation using mij application. This is not the biggest issue. I have managed to do so with the following code

```
    Bitmap memoryImage = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height,
                    PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    using (Graphics memoryGrahics =
            Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage))
    {
        memoryGrahics.CopyFromScreen(rc.X, rc.Y,
            0, 0, rc.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    }
    return new Bitmap(memoryImage, 800, 600);
```

But, when a video file is being played it only shows a black square. It seems like the media is played on a different layer en thus not captured.

How can i create a screenshot with an image of the video? I searched alot about directx or windowsapicodepack but i don't exactly know if it is the right way to do this

Comment: If I remember correctly Media embedded in Powerpoint presentations, word etc when played are Rendering infront of the window, not as an actual part of it, so if you are capturing the area, you are going to need to look at it differently.